# Dockerize NextJS Application with Prisma

Tags: docker, next.js, prisma

I have created a NextJS application, to connect to the database I use Prisma. When I start the application on my computer everything works. Unfortunately, I get error messages when I try to run the application in a Docker container. The container can be created and started. The start page of the application can also be shown (there are no database queries there yet). However, when I click on the first page where there is a database query I get error code 500 - Initial Server Error and the following error message in the console:

```
PrismaClientInitializationError: Unknown PRISMA_QUERY_ENGINE_LIBRARY undefined. Possible binaryTargets: darwin, darwin-arm64, debian-openssl-1.0.x, debian-openssl-1.1.x, rhel-openssl-1.0.x, rhel-openssl-1.1.x, linux-arm64-openssl-1.1.x, linux-arm64-openssl-1.0.x, linux-arm-openssl-1.1.x, linux-arm-openssl-1.0.x, linux-musl, linux-nixos, windows, freebsd11, freebsd12, openbsd, netbsd, arm, native or a path to the query engine library.
You may have to run prisma generate for your changes to take effect.
    at cb (/usr/src/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:38689:17)
    at async getServerSideProps (/usr/src/.next/server/pages/admin/admin.js:199:20)
    at async Object.renderToHTML (/usr/src/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:428:24)
    at async doRender (/usr/src/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:1144:38)
    at async /usr/src/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:1236:28
    at async /usr/src/node_modules/next/dist/server/response-cache.js:64:36 {
  clientVersion: '3.6.0',
  errorCode: undefined
}
```

My Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile

# base image
FROM node:16-alpine3.12

# create & set working directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src
WORKDIR /usr/src

# copy source files
COPY . /usr/src

COPY package*.json ./
COPY prisma ./prisma/

# install dependencies
RUN npm install

COPY . .

# start app
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm run start
```

My docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: web
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    env_file:
      - .env
```

My package.json:

```
{
    "name": "supermarket",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "lint": "next lint"
    },
    "prisma": {
        "schema": "prisma/schema.prisma"
      },
    "dependencies": {
        "@prisma/client": "^3.6.0",
        "axios": "^0.22.0",
        "cookie": "^0.4.1",
        "next": "latest",
        "nodemailer": "^6.6.5",
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
        "react-dom": "17.0.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "eslint": "7.32.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "11.1.2",
        "prisma": "^3.6.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `volumes:` are hiding everything the Dockerfile does and replacing it with content from the host.  Is that a potential source of trouble; does deleting the `volumes:` block help?  The error message also suggests running `prisma generate`; have you tried that?

Comment: To be honest I don't exactly know what's happening there, I don't have much experience with docker. Removing "volumes:" doesn't solve the problem. I tried to run Prisma generate but to be honest I don't know where to run it. Can you tell me where I have to do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm trying to fix this for few days now. I will post an answer if I find anything.

Answer (score 8):

I've found the error. I think it's a problem with the M1 Chip.
I changed `node:16-alpine3.12` to `node:lts` and added some commands to the Dockerfile which looks like this now:

```
# base image
FROM node:lts

# create & set working directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src
WORKDIR /usr/src

# copy source files
COPY . /usr/src

COPY package*.json ./
COPY prisma ./prisma/

RUN apt-get -qy update && apt-get -qy install openssl

# install dependencies
RUN npm install

RUN npm install @prisma/client

COPY . .
RUN npx prisma generate --schema ./prisma/schema.prisma
# start app
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm run start
```

I hope this can also help other people

Comment: I encountered `Error: Cannot find module '/root/.npm/_npx/1/lib/node_modules/prisma/scripts/preinstall-entry.js'` when try to run `npx prisma generate` or `npx prisma db push`. How did you fixed this issue?

Comment: I got different issue now: error /usr/src/app/node_modules/favicons/node_modules/sharp: Command failed.

Answer (score 2):

I have been having a similar issue, which I have just solved.

I think what you need to do is change the last block in your docker file to this

```
# start app
RUN npm run build
RUN npx prism generate
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm run start
```

I think that will solve your issue.

Comment: The answer doesn't focuses on actual problem

Answer (score 1):

I've found this solution with some workarounds:
https://gist.github.com/malteneuss/a7fafae22ea81e778654f72c16fe58d3
In short:

```
# Dockerfile

...
FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
RUN npx prisma generate                   # <---important to support Prisma query engine in Alpine Linux in final image
RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:16-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app
...
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static
COPY --chown=nextjs:nodejs prisma ./prisma/                # <---important to support Prisma DB migrations in bootstrap.sh
COPY --chown=nextjs:nodejs bootstrap.sh ./
...
CMD ["./bootstrap.sh"]
```

This Dockerfile is based on the [official Nextjs with Docker example project](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile) and adapted to include Prisma. To run migrations on app start we can add a bash script that does so:

```
# bootstrap.sh

#!/bin/sh
# Run migrations
DATABASE_URL="postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/appdb?sslmode=disable" npx prisma migrate deploy
# start app
DATABASE_URL="postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/workler?sslmode=disable" node server.js
```

Unfortunately, we need to explicitly set the DATABASE_URL here, otherwise migrations don't work, because Prisma can't find the environment variable (e.g. from a docker-compose file).
And last but not least, because Alpine Linux base image uses a Musl C-library, the Prisma client has to be compiled in the builder image against that. So, to get the correct version, we need to add this info to Prisma's `schema.prisma` file:

```
# schema.prisma

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native", "linux-musl"] # <---- important to support Prisma Query engine in Alpine linux, otherwise "PrismaClientInitializationError2 [PrismaClientInitializationError]: Query engine binary for current platform "linux-musl" could not be found."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line in schema.prisma

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native", "linux-musl", "debian-openssl-1.1.x"] // <== Add "linux-musl", "debian-openssl-1.1.x"
}
```

Then run "prisma generate" for your changes to take effect.

Comment: It was enough to add `binaryTargets = ["native"]` this end.

Answer (score 0):

---

I had a luck this way:

```
FROM node:17-slim as dependencies


# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package and lockfile
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
COPY prisma ./prisma/
RUN apt-get -qy update && apt-get -qy install openssl

# install dependencies
RUN yarn --frozen-lockfile

COPY . .

# ---- Build ----
FROM dependencies as build
# install all dependencies

# build project
RUN yarn build

# ---- Release ----
FROM dependencies as release
# copy build
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/public ./public

# dont run as root
USER node

# expose and set port number to 3000
EXPOSE 3000
ENV PORT 3000

# enable run as production
ENV NODE_ENV=production

# start app
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```